# Cannot call value of non-function type 'CIImage?'

Tags: swift

This code does compile perfectly fine

```
let ciImage = CIImage(image:UIImage())
```

however when I move it into an extension of `UIImage`

```
extension UIImage {
    func foo() {
        let ciImage = CIImage(image:UIImage()) // compile error
    }
}
```

I get the following compile error

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'CIImage?'
```

Why?

---

*Tested with Xcode Playground 7.1.1. and Swift 2.1*

Comment: Very interesting question. I've never run into that one before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's because, once inside UIImage, the term `CIImage` is seen as the `CIImage` *property* of UIImage, due to implicit `self` as message recipient — in other words, Swift turns your `CIImage` into `self.CIImage` and it's all downhill from there.

You can solve this by disambiguating thru Swift's use of module namespacing:

```
extension UIImage {
    func foo() {
        let ciImage = UIKit.CIImage(image:UIImage())
    }
}
```

**EDIT** In Swift 3 this problem will go away, because all properties will start with small letters. The property will be named `ciImage`, and there will be no confusion with the CIImage class.