# Swift 3.0: compiler error when calling global func min<T>(T,T) in Array or Dictionary extension

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, swift-extensions

After converting from Swift 2.2 to 3.0 my `Array` extension does not compile anymore, because it contains a call to global standard library function `min<T>(T,T)` and shows compiler error `extra argument in call`.

Here's a simple way to reproduce the error:

```
extension Array {
    func smallestInt(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int {
        return min(first, second) // compiler error: "Extra argument in call"
    }
}
```

I get the same error when adding the same function to an extension of `Dictionary`, while the exact same code compiles just fine in an extension of other types (e.g. `String` or `AudioBuffer`):

[image: compiler errors in Array and Dictionary extensions]

Looking at the documentation of `Array` and `Dictionary`, I find that there are instance methods on `Sequence` named `public func min() -> Element?` and `public func min(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?`. While both `String` and `AudioBuffer` do not have any kind of `min(...)` function.

Is it possible that this is the reason why I can't call the global function? The compiler can't distinguish between global `func min<T>(T,T)` and `self.min(...)` although they have completely different signatures?

Is this a bug or a feature? What am I doing wrong? How can I call `min(T,T)` correctly inside an `Array` extension?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to resolve this function call, therefore I would consider it a bug (it has already been filed – see [SR-2450](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2450)).

It seems to occur whenever attempting to call a top-level function with the same name, but unambiguously different signature to a method or property that's accessible from the same scope in a given type (instance or static).

An even simpler example would be:

```
func foo(_ a: Int) {}

struct Foo {

    func foo() {} // or static func foo() {}, var foo = 0, static var foo = 0

    func bar() {
        foo(2) // error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments
    }
}
```

Until fixed, a simple solution would be to prefix the call with the name of the module in which it resides in order to disambiguate that you're referring to the top-level function, rather than the instance one. For the standard library, that's `Swift`:

```
extension Array {
    func smallestInt(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int {
        return Swift.min(first, second)
    }
}
```

---

In Swift 4, the compiler has a better diagnostic for this error (though the fact that it's still an error is a bug IMO):

```
extension Array {
    func smallestInt(first: Int, second: Int) -> Int {
        // Use of 'min' refers to instance method 'min(by:)'
        // rather than global function 'min' in module 'Swift'
        // - Use 'Swift.' to reference the global function in module 'Swift'
        return min(first, second)
    }
}
```

Although what's interesting is that the compiler will *now* also warn on attempting to call a standard library method with the same name as a stdlib top-level function:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {

    func smallest() -> Element? {
        // Use of 'min' treated as a reference to instance method in protocol 'Sequence'
        // - Use 'self.' to silence this warning
        // - Use 'Swift.' to reference the global function
        return min()
    }
}
```

In this case, as the warning says, you can silence it by using an explicit `self.`:

```
extension Array where Element : Comparable {

    func smallest() -> Element? {
        return self.min()
    }
}
```

Although what's really curious about this warning is it doesn't *appear* to extend to non-stdlib defined functions:

```
func foo(_ a: Int) {}

struct Foo {

    func foo() {}

    func bar() {
        foo() // no warning...
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, @Hamish; you beat me to it. I recognized the symptoms immediately, because it is very similar to the problem I discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107042/341994

Comment: @matt, Hamish: Does one of you know what the module name in a Playground is? The question came up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110700/swift-function-in-class-definition-cant-found-another-global-function-with-simi#comment71391472_42110700.

Comment: ... and what about a Swift REPL?

Comment: @MartinR Interesting question! As far as I know, playgrounds are wrapped in their own Cocoa/Cocoa Touch applications when run, so even if you could work out the module name, I doubt it would be stable across different runnings of the same playground. Regarding REPL, I have no idea. Would probably be worth asking this as a formal question :)

Comment: @MartinR If you're interested, in Swift 4, playgrounds now have a module name `Playground` (and Swift 4 now gives a better diagnostic that tells you the module name to use). Although for REPL, the module name the diagnostic gives doesn't work.