# Using overridden math function

Tags: swift, function, scope

Trying to compile this code

```
pow(10,2)
struct Test {
  var i:Int
  func pow(_ p:Int) -> Int { return pow(i,p) }
}
var s = Test(i:10)
s.pow(2)
```

gives me a compiler error. Obviously the standard math.h function `pow` was blinded out by Swift's scoping rules. This rather smells like a compiler error since the math.h version of `pow` has a different signature. Is there any way to invoke it, though?

Comment: This is a bug – see [Swift 3.0: compiler error when calling global func min<T>(T,T) in Array or Dictionary extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602298/swift-3-0-compiler-error-when-calling-global-func-mintt-t-in-array-or-dicti). The solution is to disambiguate by using the module name where the function resides.

Comment: Although in your case, there's no `pow` overload for `(Int, Int) -> Int` in the first place – calling `pow(10,2)` actually uses the overload `(Decimal, Int) -> Decimal`

Comment: `pow` returns (and accepts) a Decimal, not an Int - I think the compiler is lost because of type inference. This suddenly works [with these annoying modifications](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxOd1fuS1xElIcTcfPt3E_QldJJf1cBTXU) but it indeed looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: Indeeded it takes and returns Decimal. But even `return Int(pow(Decimal(i),p))` does not solve the issue.

Comment: @EricAya Though your modification compiles, it can not be used since I need the internal Int and also Int as result :-(

Comment: Who ever put that "That solved my problem" has likely the right link. But that does not "solve my problem". It just answers the question :-(

Comment: @ThomasKilian Yep, indeed, and I can't find a solution right now. :/ I suppose a workaround would be to cast/translate Decimal to Int but I can't find a satisfying way.

Comment: What about going via floating point: `{ return lrint(Darwin.pow(Double(i),Double(p))) }` ?

Comment: cool! Until they fix that bug I will live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems: The first is how `pow(i,p)` is resolved.
As described in [Swift 3.0: compiler error when calling global func min<T>(T,T) in Array or Dictionary extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602298/swift-3-0-compiler-error-when-calling-global-func-mintt-t-in-array-or-dicti), this
can be solved by prepending the module name to the function call.

The second problem is that *there is no `pow` function* taking
two integer arguments. There is

```
public func powf(_: Float, _: Float) -> Float
public func pow(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double
```

in the standard math library, and

```
public func pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal
```

in the Foundation library. So you have to choose which one to use,
for example:

```
struct Test {
    var i:Int
    func pow(_ p:Int) -> Int {
        return lrint(Darwin.pow(Double(i),Double(p)))
    }
}
```

which converts the arguments to `Double` and rounds the result
back to `Int`.

Alternatively, use iterated multiplication:

```
struct Test {
    var i: Int
    func pow(_ p:Int) -> Int {
        return (0..<p).reduce(1) { $0.0 * i }
    }
}
```

I observed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142850/35991 that
this is faster for small exponents. Your mileage may vary.