# Swift function in class definition can't found another global function with similar name but different parameters

Tags: swift, function, signature

Function in class call another function in global will get error as bellow:

I have just write the code bellow in playground.

```
func getIntPlus(from from: Int, with message: String) -> Int {
    print("message: \(message)")
    return from + 1
}

class myIntClass {

    func getIntPlus(fromAnotherInt fromAnotherInt: Int) -> Int {
        return getIntPlus(from: fromAnotherInt, with: "hello") // error here
    }

}

getIntPlus(from: 1, with: "hi")
```

I will get error:

> error: extra argument 'with' in call return getIntPlus(from:
>   fromAnotherInt, with: "hello")

According the error, it can't found the global function in the class function define area. Strange for me.

Comment: As pointed out in the duplicate, this is a known bug and the workaround is to reference the global function via `Modulename.getIntPlus(...)`.

Comment: ok, just one more question, what Modulename would be in playground.

Comment: That is a good question! – It *seems* to be empty (so that the workaround does not work).

Comment: The workaround works for me, and the playground's problem can just leave it since this bug is a know bug.