# Swift: How to call non-class function if I have the same function in my class?

Tags: swift, swift3

I know that I can just change names, but is there another way to solve this?

```
class MyClass{
    func print(_ string: String) {
        // I'm trying to call a native print method.
        // Results in error, because it's trying to do recursion.
        print(string, terminator: ";")
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want the call to `print` to actually call the pre-defined `Swift.print`?

Comment: Also see: [Swift 3.0: compiler error when calling global func min<T>(T,T) in Array or Dictionary extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878)

Comment: In this case, there's really no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to resolve the call to `print(_:terminator:)` to Swift's `print` rather than yours.

Answer (score 3):

For global Swift builtins you can call `Swift.whatever(argument)`, so in this case:

```
Swift.print(string, terminator: ";")
```