# Within NSDocument subclass, print() is getting a fixme to printDocument()

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

Within a subclass of `NSDocument`, `print()` is getting a fixme to `printDocument()`, is this a bug? My intention is want to print something into the Xcode console.

It won't let me build, it raise as an error. Look at the image below.

I am on Xcode Version 9.0 beta (9M136h)

[image: print fixme to printDocument]

This is my first time in a situation where print has two distinctively meanings within a context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How to call non-class function if I have the same function in my class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559175/swift-how-to-call-non-class-function-if-i-have-the-same-function-in-my-class)

Comment: ok, should this consider a bug or in this context I should explicitly call the print function, since print was meant to be printDocument in this context?

Comment: It's not really a bug, you're calling `self.print(_:)`, which has been renamed to `printDocument(_:)`, so as long as the internal declaration for `print` exists, you'll see this error; https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515154-printdocument?changes=latest_minor

Comment: The same applies for e.g. `NSView`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483705-printview?changes=latest_minor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Swift 4

I use:

```
Swift.print(...)
```

and it gave the expected result