# Swift 3.1 error: cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift3

> When I try the following code:

```
extension Int{

   func hello(to end: Int, by step: Int, task: (Int) -> Void ){

        for i in stride(from: 4, to: 8, by: 2) {

            task(i)
         }
     }
}
```

> And I get the error saying:
>
> error: cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Int, to: Int, by: Int)' for i in stride(from: 4, to: 8, by: 2)
>
> note: overloads for 'stride' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (to: Self, by: Self.Stride), (through: Self, by: Self.Stride)
>           for i in stride(from: 4, to: 8, by: 2)

I don't why this type of error happens

Comment: I cannot say why this particular error occurs but it works as expected if it's not in an `Int` extension.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878. The problem in your specific case is that the compiler is seeing the Swift 2 `stride` methods, which were declared as instance members rather than global functions (but are now unavailable). The solution is the same, prefix the call with the module name to disambiguate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of tricky! :)

`Int` apparently declares its own `stride` methods (that's why the compiler shows you that partially matching overloads exist), but somehow I can't access them (compiler says that they are marked unavailable). Since you are in an `Int` extension, calling `stride` in this context is equivalent to `self.stride`. And the `stride` methods that `Int` has does not have the arguments `from:to:by:`, so it does not compile.

You want to specifically refer to the `stride` method that's global. Just specify the module in which the method is defined, i.e. `Swift`:

```
extension Int{

   func hello(to end: Int, by step: Int, task: (Int) -> Void ){

        for i in Swift.stride(from: 4, to: 8, by: 2) {

            task(i)
         }
     }
}
```