# Swfit3.0 reduce - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift

I want to implement the ratio of each to the maximum in a set of elements
My code:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == CGFloat {
    func normalize() -> [CGFloat] {
        let maxVal = self.reduce(0) { max($0, $1) }
        return self.map { $0 / maxVal }
    }
}
```

My error:

```
argument passed to call that takes no arguments
        let maxVal = self.reduce(0) { max($0, $1) }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878

Comment: @Hamish: That is the same problem. Should we close as duplicate (and I'll delete my answer)?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I guess it is a duplicate. I just didn't want to close initially due to the fact that OP can just use the instance `max()` method to begin with

Comment: @Hamish: Thank you vary much!