# What is the namespace of Swift's type(of:) function?

Tags: swift, namespaces

I have the following Swift class:

```
class Foo: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  let type: Int = 0
  var debugDescription: String {
    return "<\(type(of:self)) type: \(type)>"
  }
}
```

And Xcode 9.2 complains:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
```

I suppose this is because my local `type` conflicts with Swift's global `type`. What is the Swift global namespace so I can disambiguate?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/1187415.

Comment: Swift is not Objective-C, unless you have a very good reason to, don't inherit from `NSObject` and don't mark your classes `@objc`. Even if you had a reason to do that in your real class, those are definitely not needed for an MCVE.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this question is getting downvoted. It seems pretty clear to me. Also, @DavidPasztor OP is not asking a question about ObjC. He's asking about the `type(of:)` function.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I am aware of that, but if there's something wrong in the code posted in the question, it's everyone's best interest to point that out even if that particular issue is not related to the issue in question...

Comment: I made this a pure swift problem. Maybe I'll get some upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Swift` is the Swift global namespace name, so my class should be:

```
class Foo: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
  let type: Int = 0
  var debugDescription: String {
    return "<\(Swift.type(of:self)) type: \(type)>"
  }
}
```