# Random cannot be used on instance Int, behaviour on Linux

Tags: swift, linux

I am trying to figure out how to make the below code compile on linux. The solution for Darwin `self.init(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperLimit)))` works well, but `self.init(random() % upperLimit)` generates the error below.

```
extension Int {
    /// Initializes a new `Int ` instance with a random value below a given `Int`.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - randomBelow: The upper bound value to create a random value with.
    public init?(randomBelow upperLimit: Int) {
        guard upperLimit > 0 else { return nil }
        #if os(Linux)
            self.init(random() % upperLimit)
        #else
            self.init(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upperLimit)))
        #endif
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: repl.swift:11:27: error: static member 'random' cannot be used on instance of type 'Int'
                self.init(random() % upperLimit)
                          ^~~~~~
                          Self.
```

- I have a hunch this can be fixed with getters, but I wasn't able to find the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're receiving this error, then presumably you're using Swift 4.2 that comes with [a new random API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md). The error is arising because the compiler thinks you're trying to refer to the new static [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2995514-random) method on `FixedWidthInteger`, which `Int` conforms to (the fact that it ignores the global function [is a known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878)).

To generate a random `Int` from 0 up to (but not including) a given upper bound `n`, you can now just say:

```
let i = Int.random(in: 0 ..< n)
```

See [the above linked proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md) for more info on the new random API.

Given how simple the new API is, I'd argue that there's no need to implement a custom 
`init?(randomBelow:)`. However, if still want to, you can implement it like so:

```
extension Int {
  /// Initializes a new `Int ` instance with a random value below a given `Int`.
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - randomBelow: The upper bound value to create a random value with.
  public init?(randomBelow upperLimit: Int) {
    guard upperLimit > 0 else { return nil }
    self = .random(in: 0 ..< upperLimit)
  }
}
```

The new random API is cross-platform, so there's now no need to do any conditional compilation.