# max(_:_:) and min(_:_:) in an Int extension in Swift

Tags: swift, max, min, instancetype

Why are max(*:*:) and min(*:*:) not allowed in a Swift Int extension, such as:

```
extension Int {
    func some(low: Int, high: Int) -> Int {
        return max(low, high)
    }
}
```

The error says: `Static member 'max' cannot be used on instance of type'Int'`

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878 – you currently have to say `Swift.max(low, high)`.

Comment: The compiler needs some help here. It thinks you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1540171-max

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler needs some help here. It thinks you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/1540171-max

As Hamish says, you can disambiguate within this context to specify the global function by calling it `Swift.max`.

Comment: A perfect - thank you, matt. I was not aware that there is a `Swift.`-keyword.

Comment: Might want to learn about namespaces and modules, very basic Swift stuff. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_modules