# Mysterious "extra argument in call" error in Array extension method

Tags: arrays, swift3, extension-methods

This compiles:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<[$0 + chunkSize, self.count].min()!])
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't (substituting the global `min()` function for the array `min()` method):

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize:Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)]) // error
        }
    }
}
```

The compile error points to `self.count` and says "extra argument in call".

But if we're not in an Array extension, the second formulation is fine:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
let chunkSize = 2
let chunks = stride(from: 0, to: arr.count, by: chunkSize).map {
    Array(arr[$0..<min($0 + chunkSize, arr.count)]) // fine
}
```

So, is the compile error in the second formulation actually a Swift compiler bug? If not, what's wrong with the second formulation? I'm aware that "extra argument in call" is often a poor description of the problem coming from the Swift compiler, but then what's the *real* problem? Why does being inside an Array extension trigger this error?

Comment: It's a poor error for [the problem described here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878) – although in Swift 3.1, the diagnostic is *greatly* improved to "*Use of 'min' refers to instance method 'min(by:)' rather than global function 'min' in module 'Swift'*"

Comment: @Hamish Your comment caused me to see a bit of SO interface I've never seen before, _offering_ to let me _self-mark_ this as a duplicate. Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is conflating `Swift.Array.min(by:)`, which only takes a single argument, with the global function `Swift.min(_:_:)` that you're intending to use.

Explicitly qualifying the global function by prefixing it with its module name (`Swift`) resolves the issue:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)]) // fixed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL so the answer is actually implicit in the question's first formulation. This is actually similar to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107042/341994 Oh, the irony!

Comment: Did I ... Did I just answer a question for the Swift overlord, @matt?! :O

Comment: I don't know about that, but it was a perfect answer! Clear, concise, includes the solution. Can't ask more than that.