# Swift: Pair in groups, Algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, group-by

Am writing an algorithm to pair people in groups, presently, i can do two per group and that's if the number of people i want to group is an even number.

I need help to optimize the algorithm to add two functionalities,

1) Take care of odd numbers, everyone must be in a group

2) The number of people per group should be dynamic, i can decide to pair in 2, 3, 4 e.t.c

```
class Pair{

  var key: String?
  var value: String?

 init(key: String, value: String) {
     self.key = key
     self.value = value
   }
}



var pairList = [Pair]()

var names = ["Titi", "Bolu", "Tope", "Lola",  "bolaji", "Idowu", "Philips", "Franka", "Dolphin", "Dolapo"]

//names.shuffle()

var counter = 0
for f in stride(from: 1, through: names.count, by: 2) {

 var pair = Pair(key: names[counter], value: names[counter+1])
 pairList.append(pair)
  counter = counter + 2
}

names.removeAll()

for par in pairList{
   print("\(par.key)" + " and " + "\(par.value)")
 }
```

Comment: This question is unrelated, but its code does exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42638329/3141234

Comment: Also, you should consider just using a 2 element tuple rather than a class for `Pair`.

Comment: See [Swift: what is the right way to split up a \[String\] resulting in a \[\[String\]\] with a given subarray size?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26395766/2976878)

Comment: @Alexander, thanks man that's what i need, i just have to understand how it works

Comment: @Hamish link is a great place to start, thanks

Comment: "Pairing" things means arranging them in pairs, which are always size 2.  You want to *group* people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link @Alexander shared this is what works
[Mysterious "extra argument in call" error in Array extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42638329/3141234)

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by chunkSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: chunkSize).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + chunkSize, self.count)]) // fixed
        }
    }
}
```